# One-time registration email link

Tags: navigation, users

I need to send to specific persons one-time registration email links, in order to create users with specific roles. The "normal" registration should be available as well.

Comment: Do you want to send just an random email with this link or an user registration email?

Comment: I want to send an email such as when the receiver clicks it, it redirects to a "special" registration page, and when finished the registration form, creates a user with predefined roles. Nobody can acces that page without a one-time link.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with special page but with `user_pass_reset_url($account);` you get that url that links to pass reset page

Comment: I know, but what I want is not to reset the password of an existent user, I want to register a new user, like the form presented when you visit /user/register

Comment: you should implement `hook_form()` for your registration form and `hook_form_submit()` where your new user will be created and mail send

Comment: But, what I want is another thing... What I want is not send an email when user is created, but send an email with a one-time link (as those sent to reset passwords) to register a new user. This one-time link I want gives permission to a particular registration page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30348/discussion-between-fernando-pap-and-benone).